# COleClientItem::CreateFromFile() is strange on Windows11 but is OK on Windows10

Tags: c++, mfc, ole, windows-11

I got a strange result when executed the next code:

```
BOOL ret = pOleClientItem->CreateFromFile("a-bitmap-file.bmp");
```

On Windows11 but it is OK on Windows10 (pOleClientItem is a pointer to COleClientItem instance object).

The return code is TRUE, but that object's surface is not correctly drawn (on Windows11).

I tried the following,

I tried .png file instead .bmp file, and got a same result.
I tried CreateFromClipboard(), and got a same result.
a-bitmap-file.bmp is full-path.
a-bitmap-file.bmp is set security policy as full-control.

Comment: Can you describe what "object's surface is not correctly drawn (on Windows11)" means?

Comment: I put a CDrawOleObj instance with a COleClientItem in it on a CFormView, and give a-bitmap-file to the CDrawOleObj, then

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My question is why the program does well on Windows10 but does not on Windows11.